# Lubuntu 21.04: Install CUDA

Tags: lubuntu, cuda

I need to install CUDA (and later cuDNN) on Lubuntu 21.04.

I have updated to NVIDIA drivers (my GPU is a legacy one so I am using NVIDIA 390 drivers) and now am trying to install CUDA but cannot. I previously failed to install it and needed to reinstall lubuntu because the drivers failed.

I have tried using `sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit gcc-6`

but get the error: `Package 'gcc-6' has no installation candidate`.

I would really appreciate some help. Thanks.

Comment: Do you really need gcc-6? You can use gcc-10 instead, which is available in the Ubuntu 21.04 repositories.

Comment: What is your GPU?  Not only may it limit drivers available, but also the CUDA release. Does your dnn version require a minimum CUDA release? Hopefully you can come up with a compatible set of releases for drivers, CUDA, and dnn.

Answer (score 0):

OK I seemed to have installed it.
I changed the command to:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit gcc-10
```